# What is the TYPE_MINIMUM constant in the gnu-coreutils source files?

Tags: c, linux, gnu-coreutils

I'm trying to reimplement some of the coreutils for a project, and I'm seeing TYPE_MINIMUM(some int) a lot, however I can't see where it's defined or any usage for it. I'm not sure if it's something that's generated during make, or if it was intentional. Any ideas?

I have included all the headers that are required for the functions, and everything works up until the TYPE_MINIMUM is called for a validation.

Complete source for file being used: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/who.c

```
static const char *idle_string (time_t when, time_t boottime)
{
    static time_t now = TYPE_MINIMUM (time_t);

    if (now == TYPE_MINIMUM (time_t))
        time (&now);

    if (boottime < when && now - 24 * 60 * 60 < when && when <= now)
    {
        int seconds_idle = now - when;
        if (seconds_idle < 60)
            return "  .  ";
        else
        {
            static char idle_hhmm[IDLESTR_LEN];
            /* FIXME-in-2018: see if this assert is still required in order
               to suppress gcc's unwarranted -Wformat-length= warning.  */
            assert (seconds_idle / (60 * 60) < 24);
            sprintf (idle_hhmm, "%02d:%02d",
                     seconds_idle / (60 * 60),
                     (seconds_idle % (60 * 60)) / 60);
            return idle_hhmm;
        }
    }

    return (" old ");
}
```

```
error: ‘TYPE_MINIMUM’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: It's probably some macro that gives you a value like those from <limits.h> and the limits in <stdint.h> according to the type you pass it.

Comment: Makes sense. The problem is, how would I rewrite this without that macro, or where is that macro defined so that I can use it to have this function work as intended?

Comment: Actually, I found the macros through a quick google: https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/intprops.h#L56, I'll make an answer

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of this macro can be found in the Coreutils ["intprops.h" file](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/intprops.h#L56).

From that file:

```
/* The maximum and minimum values for the integer type T.  */
#define TYPE_MINIMUM(t) ((t) ~ TYPE_MAXIMUM (t))
#define TYPE_MAXIMUM(t)                                                 \
  ((t) (! TYPE_SIGNED (t)                                               \
        ? (t) -1                                                        \
        : ((((t) 1 << (TYPE_WIDTH (t) - 2)) - 1) * 2 + 1)))
```

Where TYPE_WIDTH gives the size of a type in bits:

```
/* The width in bits of the integer type or expression T.
   Do not evaluate T.
   Padding bits are not supported; this is checked at compile-time below.  */
#define TYPE_WIDTH(t) (sizeof (t) * CHAR_BIT)
```

It gets the minimum of a type by taking the one's complement of the maximum of that type. It gets that maximum by either:

- If it's unsigned, casting the value -1 to that type
- If it's signed, adding one to twice the value obtained by subtracting one from the value obtained by setting the second-highest bit.

Although it's not really needed for your question, I want to go through that signed case. Let's take `int16_t` as an example.

If we handle that ternary and TYPE_WIDTH ahead of time, and ignore extra parentheses that ensure a little more safety `TYPE_MAXIMUM(int16_t)` expands to:

```
(int16_t) ((((int16_t) (1 << 14)) - 1) * 2 + 1)
```

Then:

```
(int16_t) ((((int16_t) 0x4000) - 1) * 2 + 1)
```

Then:

```
(int16_t) (((int16_t) 0x3FFF) * 2 + 1)
```

Then:

```
(int16_t) ((int16_t) 0x7FFE + 1)
```

Then:

```
(int16_t) ((int16_t) 0x7FFE + 1)
```

Which is:

```
(int16_t) 0x7FFF
```

`TYPE_MAXIMUM` is way to efficiently set all but the upper bit without relying on signed overflow, which yields undefined behaviour and must not be used.

This `TYPE_MAXIMUM` method does assume that any signed type given doesn't use a model where the maximum signed value is not represented by all but the highest bit being set.

A `TYPE_MINIMUM(int16_t)` would invert those bits to get `(int16_t) 0x8000`.

This `TYPE_MINIMUM` from a maximum value method assumes that any signed type given doesn't use sign-and-magnitude arithmetic, or any other model where the one's complement of a maximum held value is not the minimum value.

With these two restrictions on signed representations, the representations given in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) that will work with the `TYPE_MINIMUM` macro is one's complement and two's complement.

In practice, this will likely never be an issue, almost everything uses two's complement representations of signed integers.